# Сломалась форма обратной связи

Tags: php, форма, sendmail

Прошу помощи. На одностраничном (html) сайте сломалась форма заявки. Всего на странице 5 форм, работают через файл sendmail.php.

Код формы:

```
<?php
    define("CONTACT_FORM", 'order@rosa-montazh.com');
    
      // function ValidateEmail($value){
      //   $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';
    
      //   if($value == '') {
      //     return false;
      //   } else {
      //     $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $value);
      //   }
    
      //   return empty($string) ? true : false;
      // }
      $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
    
      $title = $_POST['form_title'];
      $nameForm = $_POST['form_nameForm'];
      $name = $_POST['form_name'];
      $email = $_POST['form_email'];
      $phone = $_POST['form_phone'];
      $area = $_POST['form_area'];
      $date = $_POST['form_date'];
      $gift = $_POST['form_gift'];
      $text = $_POST['form_text'];
      $quantity = $_POST['form_quantity'];
      if (isset($area) && isset($quantity)){
        $comments = "Площадь: ".$area." м.кв; \nКол-во помещений: ".$quantity;
      } else if (isset($date)) {
        $comments ="Заказ обратного звонка на: ".$date;
      } else if(isset($gift)) {
        $comments ="Выбранный подарок: ".$gift;
      } else if(isset($text)) {
        $comments ="Дополнение: ".$text;
      } else {
        $comments ="";
      }
    
      // create email body and send it
      $to = 'order@rosa-montazh.com'; // put your email
      $subject = "Заявка от $name | ".$title." | Сайт - Водяной теплый пол";
      $message = "Заполнена форма ".$title.". \n\n".
        "Данные отправителя:\n\nИмя: ".$name." \n".
        "Почта: ".$email." \n".
        "Телефон: ".$phone." \n".
        // "Отапливаемая площадь: ".$area." \n".
        // "Количество помещений: ".$quantity." \n".
        $comments;
      /*$headers = "From: ".$name." <".$to.">" . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: ".$name." <".$to.">" . "\r\n" ;*/
      mail($to, $subject, $message ,$headers);
      // return true;
    
      // Bitrix24
      // CRM server conect ion data
      define('CRM_HOST', '************'); // your CRM domain name
      define('CRM_PORT', '443'); // CRM server port
      define('CRM_PATH', '/crm/configs/import/lead.php'); // CRM server REST service path
    
      // CRM server authorization data
      define('CRM_LOGIN', 'order@rosa-montazh.com'); // login of a CRM user able to manage leads
      define('CRM_PASSWORD', '***************'); // password of a CRM user
      // OR you can send special authorization hash which is sent by server after first successful connection with login and password
      // define('CRM_AUTH', '******************'); // authorization hash
    
      /********************************************************************************************/
    
      // POST processing
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
      {
        $leadData = $_POST['DATA'];
    
        $title = $_POST['form_title'];
        $name = $_POST['form_name'];
        $email = $_POST['form_email'];
        $phone = $_POST['form_phone'];
        $area = $_POST['form_area'];
        $date = $_POST['form_date'];
        $gift = $_POST['form_gift'];
        $text = $_POST['form_text'];
        $quantity = $_POST['form_quantity'];
        if (isset($area) && isset($quantity)){
          $comments = "Площадь: ".$area." м.кв; \nКол-во помещений: ".$quantity;
        } else if (isset($date)) {
          $comments = "Заказ обратного звонка на: ".$date;
        } else if (isset($gift)) {
          $comments ="Выбранный подарок: ".$gift;
        } else if (isset($text)) {
          $comments ="Выбранный подарок: ".$text;
        } else {
          $comments = "";
        }
    
        // get lead data from the form
        $postData = array(
          'TITLE' => $title,
          'NAME' => $name,
          'EMAIL_OTHER' => $email,
          'PHONE_WORK' => $phone,
          'COMMENTS' => $comments,
          'SOURCE_ID' => 'Сайт теплый водяной пол',
          'STATUS_DESCRIPTION' => $title,
          // 'ASSIGNED_BY_ID' => '',
        );
    
        // append authorization data
        if (defined('CRM_AUTH'))
        {
          $postData['AUTH'] = CRM_AUTH;
        }
        else
        {
          $postData['LOGIN'] = CRM_LOGIN;
          $postData['PASSWORD'] = CRM_PASSWORD;
        }
    
        // open socket to CRM
        $fp = fsockopen("ssl://".CRM_HOST, CRM_PORT, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if ($fp)
        {
          // prepare POST data
          $strPostData = '';
          foreach ($postData as $key => $value)
            $strPostData .= ($strPostData == '' ? '' : '&').$key.'='.urlencode($value);
    
          // prepare POST headers
          $str = "POST ".CRM_PATH." HTTP/1.0\r\n";
          $str .= "Host: ".CRM_HOST."\r\n";
          $str .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
          $str .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($strPostData)."\r\n";
          $str .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    
          $str .= $strPostData;
    
          // send POST to CRM
          fwrite($fp, $str);
    
          // get CRM headers
          $result = '';
          while (!feof($fp))
          {
            $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
          }
          fclose($fp);
    
          // cut response headers
          $response = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result);
    
          $output = '<pre>'.print_r($response[1], 1).'</pre>';
        }
        else
        {
          echo 'Connection Failed! '.$errstr.' ('.$errno.')';
        }
      }
      else
      {
        $output = '';
      }
       return true;
    // HTML form
    ?>
```

По проблеме общалась с поддержкой хостинга ответили:
В логах сайта видим следующее предупреждение о параметре в 52 строке:

```
PHP Warning: mail(): headers parameter must be string or array in /var/www/u124667/data/www/vodyanoj-pol-montazh.ru/html/sendmail.php on line 52
```

В логах почтового сервера никаких данных по аккаунту нет, это значит, что почтовый сервер хостинга не используется при отправке.

[![52 строка кода][1]][1]

Буду благодарна за любую помощь.

Comment: У вас headers закомментирован жеж..

Comment: Что-то сломалось, а что именно — в ошиюке написано)))

Comment: Раскоментировала. Но проверить сейчас не могу. Есть идеи почему он был закоментирован?:

Comment: @Anna_V потому что кто-то его закомментировал, тут вариантов не много.

Comment: Позже проверю работает или нет. Спасибо за быстрые ответы ;)